# Word/expression for the inherent ambiguity or difficulty of defining what constitutes a good outcome

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests, formality, paraphrasing

**TL;DR:** I am in a need of a good, precise word or an expression capturing the notion that a computer science problem P remains open (just) because it is virtually impossible to specify/define what a good solution would look like.
Unfortunately, it needs to fit the semi-formal style of scientific writing.

**Background:**
In the past, people have argued that their solution to P is the best because  the outputs are human friendly. Other bunch of authors have argued that their answer to P is the best because the outputs of their solution to P make sense (kind of) even when tried on new, previously unseen inputs. And yet another school claims that their solution is the best because it considers a modification of the problem P - P' - that makes P a harder problem, and fares very well in that scenario.

**My attempts:**

> the problem remains open mainly due to the *inherent ambiguity in what is considered a "good'' solution*
>
> the problem remains open mainly due to the *prevalent difficulty of specifying  of what constitutes a "good" solution*
>
> the problem remains open mainly due to the *inherent vagueness in the definition of successful outcome*

Comment: The solutions lack an agreed single [measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)) of merit?

Comment: _Multifaceted_ is often used for a complex/complicated problem that has many aspects and contributing factors, and that can generate multiple outcomes/arguments. Although, your own question might be multifaceted; so let me know if this word works for you.

Comment: The expression I would use is _asking the wrong question_, or _barking up the wrong tree_, both of which have the property of using a definite article to indicate the opposite of definiteness.

Comment: The problem is not well posed.

Comment: @PhilSweet amazing, this sounds great, thank you

Comment: @ermanen "multifaceted" is unfortunately an overused word in my sub-field and is essentially a no-no like "so-called"

Comment: @JohnLawler thanks, but "asking the wrong question" could be perceived by reviewers as accusatory, while "barking up the wrong tree" would perhaps make my work sounds a bit unprofessional

Comment: @aparente001 To claim ill-posedness I would have to provide a proof. I'll consider it, but since this is to go into an introductory section, I'd rather keep it light on the claims' side

Comment: Possibly _open-ended_ problem. Here is a definition I've found on [umich.edu](http://websites.umich.edu/~scps/html/probsolv/open/oep.htm): "Open-ended problems are those which have many solutions or no solutions for the problem as defined." If one wants to be more concrete, _insoluble_ can be used, "due to its insolubility".

Answer (score 1):

Your attempts are actually quite accurate in describing your situation. I find your 2nd example best.

I might suggest:

> According to [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/nigh-impossible):
>
> > *nigh impossible*: Something that is impossible cannot be done or cannot happen

> the problem is mainly open due to it being *nigh impossible* to define what constitutes a good solution

Comment: Thanks. But it does change the meaning I am afraid. The problem itself does admit a few solutions, but judging their quality and definitiveness is difficult

Comment: Perhaps *due to it being nigh impossible to define what constitutes a good solution* would fly?

Comment: Yes that would work @user35443